# No Content-Security-Policy HTTP header created after "run generate" with Nuxt JS

Tags: nuxt.js, content-security-policy

my nuxt version:" 2.12.2 "

I'm trying to get render:csp to work but no **Content-Security-Policy HTTP header added** after "run generate" process it only works in "run dev"

and my config csp is :

```
render: {
        csp: {            
            reportOnly: false,
            addMeta: true,
            hashAlgorithm: 'sha256',
            unsafeInlineCompatibility: false,
            policies: {
                'script-src': [
                    "'unsafe-inline'",
                    "'unsafe-eval'",
                ]
            },
            allowedSources: ALLOWED_SOURCES
        }
    },
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Pls have a look this thread: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6592 it looks like NuxtJS in SPA mode does not support CSP at all, and have a bugs with CSP in SSR mode.